# Error al crear un nuevo proyecto despues de actualizar Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Saludos compañeros, resulta que despues de actualizar a Android Studio 2.2 (yo tenia la 2.1) ahora no puedo crear nuevos proyectos porq me da este error:

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

Alguien le ha pasado lo mismo? mi laptop es una HP AMD dual-Core con 3gb de RAM, porq esta nueva actualización no me deja crear nuevos proyectos? hasta la versión 2.1 venia trabajando sin problemas, gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: Actualiza el JDK a la versión 1.8

Answer (score 2):

Hola tuve ese problema recientemente, lo logré solucionar con una des las respuestas mencionadas [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio) por @Shiri

Basicamente lo que dice es que debes:

1. Abrir el archivo **gradle.properties** de tu proyecto
2. Agregar esta linea **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m** (puede que ya la tengas pero con otro valor, en ese caso remplazala).
3. Vuelve a sincronizar el gradle.

Espero eso te sirva, tuve el mismo problema y así fue que lo solucione.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

He actualizado e instalado varias ocasiones el Android Studio 2.2 y no he tenido ningun problema

De acuerdo a tu mensaje de error el problema es al iniciar el Daemon:

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.  This problem might be
>   caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.  For example, an
>   unrecognized jvm option is used.  Please refer to the user guide
>   chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>   Please read the following process output to find out more:
>   **Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap**

El error indicado hace enfasis en que la Maquina Virtual no puede reservar suficiente espacio...

Ve a `Help` > `Edit Custom VM OPtions...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te pedira seguramente crear el archivo `studio.vmoptions`, dentro agregas la siguiente configuracion:

```
-Xms256m 
-Xmx2048m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Prueba nuevamente!

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios voy a probar

Answer (score 0):

Es problema lo tuve en el 2015 cuando actualice, la solucion que me funciono fue cerrar android studio, despues ir a la carpeta .gradle y cambiarle de nombre, al correr de nuevo android studio me funciono bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, ya hice lo que indicaste y nada sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

He estado investigando este error y he encontrado la respuesta después de buscar un poco y encontré la respuesta.

Me parece que la respuesta en el sitio web: [www.experts-exchange.com/...](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28828160/Android-Studio-Gradle-project-sync-failed.html)

Este problema se produce debido a la memoria reservada para el IDE es demasiado baja. así que lo que necesitamos para anular el son ellos.

Proceder así ...

Con IDE Android abierta, sólo agregar esta línea de código en **gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m
```

y ahora u Haga clic en Try Again...

### El archivo se vería así:

---

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m

# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

---

Espero que le ayudó.